# a dot/period in the middle of an IPA

Tags: ipa

This IPA symbol comes from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/funny)

[image]

There is a dot/period in the middle of the symbol, pointed out by red arrow. What does that mean?

It seems a little bit counterintuitive if consider it the boundary of sound. Is it more reasonable to use notation this way?

`/ˈfʌ.ni/` or `fu . nny`

Comment: The period is used to indicate a syllable boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The period indicates a syllable break. So the syllabification is CVC.V., rather than CV.CV. Actually the latter is counter-intuitive too! That's because the first syllable is stressed and a stressed syllable normally attracts a [coda](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Coda).

I'd say the /n/ is [ambisyllabic](https://www.google.com/search?q=ambisyllabic+means&oq=ambisyllabic+means&aqs=chrome..69i57&client=ms-android-asus-tpin&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8); it belongs to both syllable.

In a tree diagram, its representation is similar to that of "shimmer".

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If you pronounce it super slowly, would you speak `fu . nny` or `funn . nny`?

Comment: @czlsws It's fun-ny